# Forcing the execution of list items in R

Tags: r, list, shiny

I've got a bunch of shiny functions in a named list that generate html. I want to be able to call an item in the list and **either** pass the shiny functions to the calling function (*bs4Dash::bs4TabPanel()*) **or** pass a chunk of compiled html to the calling function - the function will accept either.

I feel like this should be easy, but I can't quite figure it out how to do it correctly:

```
l <- list("list_item" = list(force(tags$strong("Something something...")),
                             force(tags$strong("Something else..."))))

paste(l[["list_item"]], collapse = "")
# > "list(name = \"strong\", attribs = list(), children = list(\"Something something...\"))list(name = \"strong\", attribs = list(), children = list(\"Something else...\"))"

pasted <- lapply(l[["list_item"]], paste)
paste(pasted, collapse = "")
# > "<strong>Something something...</strong><strong>Something else...</strong>"
```

It works if I make the "pasted" intermediate variable, but that seems like an unnecessary hack because I don't understand what I am doing.

**Update:**

starja's very thorough response answers the question I asked with a very helpful explanation. However... turns out my question was wrong. Just in case someone else is looking for an answer involving bs4TabPanel, it doesn't take html as an input (I thought that i had previously got it to do so). What I was doing that was failing was:

```
arguments <- c(tabName, active, l[[list_item]])
do.call(bs4TabPanel, arguments)
```

which was executing the functions in l[[list_item]] before handing them on to bs4TabPanel. What I needed was:

```
arguments <- c(tabName, active)
do.call(bs4TabPanel, c(arguments, l[[list_item]]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look what happens here (you actually don't need `force`):

```
l <- list("list_item" = list(tags$strong("Something something..."),
                              tags$strong("Something else...")))
```

Every `tags$strong` creates a list with the class `shiny.tag`:

```
str(l)
List of 1
 $ list_item:List of 2
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ name    : chr "strong"
  .. ..$ attribs : Named list()
  .. ..$ children:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr "Something something..."
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
  ..$ :List of 3
  .. ..$ name    : chr "strong"
  .. ..$ attribs : Named list()
  .. ..$ children:List of 1
  .. .. ..$ : chr "Something else..."
  .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "shiny.tag"
```

The help site for `tags` state that:

> The result from these functions is a tag object, which can be
> converted using as.character().

So if you use use `as.character`, the list becomes:

```
l_new <- lapply(l$list_item, as.character)
str(l_new)
List of 2
 $ : chr "<strong>Something something...</strong>"
 $ : chr "<strong>Something else...</strong>"
```

Now you can either choose one entry or paste them together:

```
paste0(l_new, collapse = "")
[1] "<strong>Something something...</strong><strong>Something else...</strong>"
```

But note that you do the `lapply` over `l$list_item` because your `list_item` contains two entries with text in a html tag. If you have several `list_item`s, you need to apply the `as.character` to every entry of your `list_item`s:

```
lapply(l, function(list_item) {
  res <- lapply(list_item, as.character)
  paste0(res, collapse = "")
})
```

If you want to use the html, you can either use the `tag` object:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("output_1")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  l <- list("list_item" = list(tags$strong("Something something..."),
                                tags$strong("Something else...")))
  
  output$output_1 <- renderUI({
    l$list_item[[1]]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Or you can generate the actual html and put it inside the `HTML` function:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("output_1")
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  l <- list("list_item" = list(tags$strong("Something something..."),
                                tags$strong("Something else...")))
  
  output$output_1 <- renderUI({
    HTML(as.character(l$list_item[[1]]))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```